# How to control process environment variable in Python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to change the environment of my Python execution process.  It seems that the correct way to do that should be to interact with os.environ.  However, I the following assertion fails:

```
import os, subprocess
os.environ['ATESTVARIABLE'] = 'value'
value = subprocess.check_output(['echo', '$ATESTVARIABLE'], shell=True)
assert 'value' in value
```

*Is there something else that I should be doing to change the current environment?* What flaw in my understanding of Python is revealed by the above code :)?

(Note that within the current Python interpreter, `os.environ['ATESTVARIABLE']` contains the expected value.  I am setting up to run some code which requires a specific environment variable, and which may launch external processes.  Obviously, if I wanted to control the environment of a *specific* subprocess, I'd use the env keyword.)

Comment: Your code is not valid python code, sorry. Please fix it if you expect help...

Comment: @paul- my code executes using Linux and Python 2.7.3 (other than the oexpected AssertionError).  What version of Python are you using?

Comment: ahh. I see, you meant the (now corrected) typo in check_output. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking through the source code for the `subprocess` module, it's because using a list of arguments with `shell=True` will do the equivalent of...

```
/bin/sh -c 'echo' '$ATESTVARIABLE'
```

...when what you want is...

```
/bin/sh -c 'echo $ATESTVARIABLE'
```

The following works for me...

```
import os, subprocess

os.environ['ATESTVARIABLE'] = 'value'
value = subprocess.check_output('echo $ATESTVARIABLE', shell=True)
assert 'value' in value
```

---

**Update**

FWIW, the difference between the two is that the first form...

```
/bin/sh -c 'echo' '$ATESTVARIABLE'
```

...will just call the shell's built-in `echo` with no parameters, and set `$0` to the literal string `'$ATESTVARIABLE'`, for example...

```
$ /bin/sh -c 'echo $0'
/bin/sh
$ /bin/sh -c 'echo $0' '$ATESTVARIABLE'
$ATESTVARIABLE
```

...whereas the second form...

```
/bin/sh -c 'echo $ATESTVARIABLE'
```

...will call the shell's built-in `echo` with a single parameter equal to the value of the environment variable `ATESTVARIABLE`.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, what's wrong in the following code:

```
import os, subprocess
os.environ['ATESTVARIABLE'] = 'value'
value = subprocess.check_output(['echo', '$ATESTVARIABLE'], shell=True)
assert 'value' in value
```

is that you didn't read *thoroughly* the [help page of subprocess](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor):

> On Unix with shell=True, the shell defaults to /bin/sh. If args is a string, the string specifies the command to execute through the shell. This means that the string must be formatted exactly as it would be when typed at the shell prompt. This includes, for example, quoting or backslash escaping filenames with spaces in them. **If args is a sequence, the first item specifies the command string, and any additional items will be treated as additional arguments to the shell itself**. That is to say, Popen does the equivalent of:

```
Popen(['/bin/sh', '-c', args[0], args[1], ...])
```

This means that if you call `subprocess.check_out()` with an array as a first parameter, you won't get the expected result. You shall retry with the following code:

```
import os, subprocess
os.environ['ATESTVARIABLE'] = 'value'
value = subprocess.check_output('echo $ATESTVARIABLE', shell=True)
assert 'value' in value
```

and it should work as you expect!

Otherwise, your understanding of environment variables is correct. When you modify the environment, that environment is given to every forked child of your current process.